# False Error 522: circular reference

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have a large spreadsheet: 700+ rows, each having references to the previous row. I use reference functions: `ROW()`, `COLUMN()` and `INDIRECT()`, `ADDRESS()`. (Yes, I have considered fixing values every 50-100 rows to reduce calculation trail.)

Until recently I used OpenOffice.org and it worked fine. LibreOffice, however, when the file is opened, seems to give up after some rows and further calculations become Error 522. Sometimes a change makes it re-calculate it all and errors disappear and doesn't reappear when I undo the change. I have also found out about Ctrl-Shift-F9 (must be re-calculate), which also makes errors disappear.

Even though the file has been saved and re-saved by LibreOffice several times it still reports false Error 522 when I open the file, so it doesn't seem to be compatibility problem.

Is the problem that a very long branched out calculation trail makes the software think it will never get to the initial values and therefore it must be circular? (Which my idea of fixing values would solve.) Or could there be something else I may have missed?

UPDATE

I don't see how INDEX() would help. I want to refer to a cell immediately above or a cell from a row immediately above. Cell d46 could point to d45 or b45 or $a45, and that would work when copying a row, but not when inserting or deleting a row: If you insert a row just above, the references pointing 1 row above would start pointing 2 rows above, so each time I would have to edit the formulae. The row (each row) contains several references to the row just above, so I thought the easiest way would be INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN())) for the same column or INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,1)) for column A... Any better solutions?

Comment: INDIRECT is a [volatile function](http://chandoo.org/wp/2014/03/03/handle-volatile-functions-like-they-are-dynamite/) and might be a contributor to the problem.  My first step would be to try to rewrite the function to not use INDIRECT; consider INDEX as a possible replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the specifics of the problem, but it sounds like it would help to simplify the formulas, as you suggested.

Another possibility is to write macros to handle some of the calculation work.  Besides Basic, macros can be written in Java, which you seem to be familiar with.  Macros can be called from a spreadsheet function, or called when the document is loaded.

It may also help to use a more powerful tool such as LibreOffice Base with MySQL.  Often spreadsheets that need a lot of `INDIRECT()` and `ADDRESS()` are really using database-type logic.

Comment: The spreadsheet is mirroring an account with all transactions, but keeping track of balance shares of 2 or more people and calculating accrued interest. Yes, I could directly reference the row above, but the problem with that is that inserting or deleting a row makes such references wrong. Using `INDIRECT()` and `ADDRESS()` solves this problem.

Comment: My idea was not to simplyfy the formulae, but to fix every 50th-100th row (so change all formulae in a row into the values they return) because I don't make changes/corrections more than 50-100 transactions back.